# Casting CLLocationDistance in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, casting

I'm a complete newbie using Swift and I'm having a headache trying to do something that should be quite straightforward.

I have an object Place with a variable of type Double called distance. I'm using the following code to store the distance between the  user location and some other locations:

```
var obj = res as Place
let loc = CLLocation(latitude: obj.location.lat, longitude: obj.location.lng)
let dist = CLLocation.distanceFromLocation(loc)
obj.distance = dist // ERROR
```

The last line shows me an error saying "CLLocationDistance is not convertible to 'Double'". As far I know, CLLocationDistance should be a Double. I've tried to cast that value to double and float using

```
Double(dist)
```

and

```
obj.distance = dist as Double
```

but nothing seems to work. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense `distanceFromLocation` isn't a class method on CLLocation - it is an instance method, so you need to invoke it on an existing CLLocation object.

Comment: What's the definition of `Place`? How is `distance` declared?

Comment: `CLLocationDistance` is defined as `typealias CLLocationDistance = Double`, so they are exactly equivalent to each other, which means you have some other problem.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The problem was I was wrong about using that method. Distance is defined as Double but obviously, the method is not intended to be used as I did it. Gregory Higley's answer describes the situation perfectly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason this is occurring boils down to the following line:

```
let distance = CLLocation.distanceFromLocation(loc)
```

This is not doing what you think it's doing. `distanceFromLocation` is an instance method, but you are calling it as a class method. Unlike ObjC, Swift allows this, but what you're actually getting back is not a `CLLocationDistance` but a function with the following type signature: `CLLocation -> CLLocationDistance`. You can verify this by adding in the type annotation yourself:

```
let distance: CLLocation -> CLLocationDistance = CLLocation.distanceFromLocation(loc)
```

This is called partial application and is outside the scope of my answer, except to note that the first parameter of the function assigned to `distance` would be the implicit `self` when called as an instance method.

The fix is simple:

```
let distance = loc.distanceFromLocation(loc)
```

Then everything will work as you desire, at least from the perspective of the type system, because this properly returns a `CLLocationDistance`, which is substitutable for `Double`.

Comment: Great answer, Gregory. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You need two objects of `CLLocation` with two different locations

Like as `fromLocation` and `toLocation`

Then you will get distance in

```
let distance = fromLocation.distanceFromLocation(toLocation)
```

An Example of Code for distance between old and new location :

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
    if let firstLocation = locations.first as? CLLocation
    {
        mapView.setCenterCoordinate(firstLocation.coordinate, animated: true)

        let region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(firstLocation.coordinate, 1000, 1000)
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

        if let oldLocation = oldLocation {
            let delta: CLLocationDistance = firstLocation.distanceFromLocation(oldLocation)
            totalDistane += delta
            updateDistanceLabel()
        }

        oldLocation = firstLocation
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Ashish. This is not really the answer to my question but definitely it's a good option.